# No ClassTag available compilation error

Tags: scala

The compiler keeps producing the following errors:

```
No ClassTag available for a
  val keys = Array.fill(maxSize+1){ default[a] }
                                  ^
not enough arguments for method fill: (implicit evidence$9: scala.reflect.ClassTag[a])Array[a].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$9.
  val keys = Array.fill(maxSize+1){ default[a] }
                                  ^
```

for this piece of code

```
object Utils {
  def default[a] = {
    class DefaultVal {
      var x: a = _
    }
    (new DefaultVal).x
  }
}

class IndexedHeap[a](maxSize: Int)(implicit ev: Ordering[a]) {
  import ev._
  import Utils._

  val keys = Array.fill(maxSize+1){ default[a] }

}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I think adding ClassTag would fix it, like this:

```
[a:ClassTag]
```

edit based on your comment on the conflict with implicit params and context bounds:
Change the implicit parameters to include the ClassTag too

```
implicit ev: Ordering[a], ct: ClassTag[a]
```

Comment: If I add this to class definition, compiler fails saying `Can't have both implicit parameters and context bounds`

Comment: That is true, you should add it as an implicit parameter, like implicit ev: Ordering[a], ct: ClassTag[a].